Unable to setup ACLs for Kafka on a Kraft based 3 node cluster
I am not able to enable ACL authorizer on
kafka_2.13-3.7.0 running on Ubuntu 22.04. I created a three broker Kraft cluster. When I list all the available ACLs, it gives error "No Authorizer is configured on the broker".


process.roles=broker,controller
listeners=LOOPBACK://<listener-IP>:9092,CONTROLLER:/<listener-IP>:9093,CLUSTER://<listener-IP>:9094,NORTHBOUND://<App-IP>:9095
inter.broker.listener.name=LOOPBACK
advertised.listeners=LOOPBACK://<listener-IP>:9092,CLUSTER://<listener-IP>:9094,NORTHBOUND://<App-IP>:9095
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=LOOPBACK:SASL_SSL,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,CLUSTER:SASL_SSL,NORTHBOUND:SASL_SSL
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
ssl.key.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.7.0/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.7.0/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
listener.name.loopback.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
listener.name.loopback.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
listener.name.loopback.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=kafkaadmin password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx user_kafkaadmin=xxxxxxxxxxxxx user_rambo1=xxxxxxxxxxxxx;
#### Just like above listener for loopback, below there are 9 lines where similar listener entries are there for controller, cluster and northbound. ###

super.users=User:kafkaadmin;User:akr
listener.name.sasl_ssl.security.protocol=SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,CLUSTER:SASL_SSL,NORTHBOUND:SASL_SSL
listener.name.sasl_ssl.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
listener.name.loopback.authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer
listener.name.controller.authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer
listener.name.cluster.authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer
listener.name.northbound.authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer





If additionally, I add below: 
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true 
I get an error "Connection to node -1 (hostname/<broker-ip>:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)" 
Any idea what I am doing wrong?



Any idea what I am doing wrong ?
